# Writing jQuery code

Tags: jquery

What i am doing wrong. I want to write in one field and after that opened by the following.I want thet if i enter the text in one field and after that other field are opening but other field dus not open's.  Please help me

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            if($('#name' == '')){
                $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            }
            else {
                $('#version').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');  
            }
        }); 

        $(function(){
            if($('#name' !== '')){
                $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            }
            else {
                $('#version').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        Version: <input type="text" name="version" id="version">
        Build: <input type="text" name="build" id="build">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></br>
        <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example. What you've given us isn't enough to help without making assumptions or asking more questions.

Comment: Write something about your HTML code.

Comment: [.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) only takes one argument. And your selector doesn't work. It should be `$('#version')`. But it's not clear if you are trying to determine if an element with id `version` exists or if you want to check if the element is blank.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid:

```
if($('#name' == '')){
    $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
}
```

You can use this instead:

```
if($('#name' ).length){
    $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one obvious error, to select an element in jquery, use `$('#ele')`

```
$(function(){
    if($('#name') == ''){
        $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    }
    else {
        $('#version').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
});

$(function(){
    if($('#version') == ''){
        $('#build').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    }
    else {
        $('#build').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');    
    }
});
```